# Redirect 301 in .htaccess Redirecting to other url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have redirected one of my redesigned website using this code.

```
Redirect 301 /oldurl http://www.domain.com/newurl
```

When I Used this code in my htaccess file. the Url I am getting is htt://www domain com/newurl?oldurl 
Can any one help me regarding this

Hey some one help facing the same issue again for this website: http://www.godsfood.in/

Comment: Can you please provide the code you use?

Comment: Redirect 301 /websitedevelopment /webdevelopment

Comment: When I Use this code it was redirecting to www.domain.com/webdevelopment?websitedevelopment

Comment: Hope you added `RewriteEngine on` on top .

Comment: ya I have added this on the top # Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

Comment: Can you try with quotes (") like Redirect 301 "/websitedevelopment" "/webdevelopment"

Comment: Try Redirect 301 /oldurl  /newurl

Comment: Let me try and inform you @MikaA.

Comment: That is the code I am using at present @Sree It was redirecting but the url I am getting is after redirecting is www.domain.com/webdevelopment?websitedevelopment. When I click on the old url

Comment: @MikaA. That Does't worked

Comment: What other rules do you have in the htaccess file?

Comment: I tried using this code `RewriteRule ^old.html$ /new-location/ [END,R=301]`

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ativaishna.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.Domain.com/ [R=301,L] @MikaA.

Comment: Is it before the redirect? I think apache will use this rewrite instead of your redirect

Comment: ya the redirect code is below the above code

Comment: Are you really getting redirected to a URL with no `.` in `www.domain.com`? And `http:` became `htt:`? If those are typos, please correct them so that your question is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I got this solution .Try this

```
RewriteRule ^old-location/?$ /new-location/   [END,R=301]
```

Comment: I have already tried not working for me I got this code in one of the forum